# How can I find the value of the entered elements on array in C

Tags: c

I need to get the percentage of each value inside the array. I already got the sum of the elements. For example I entered 4 elements which is 1 2 2 1,the sum will be 6. Percentage will be:
1 is 16.67percent of the sum
2 is 33.33 percent of the sum
2 is 33.33 percent of the sum
1 is 16.67percent of the sum

I don't know how can I get the value inside the entered elements on array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,sum,size;
   
    printf("ENter array length : \n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int ara[size];
    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < size;  i++){
        scanf("%d", &ara[i]);
    }
    sum=0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum+=ara[i]; 
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for BOTH `for(i = 0; i < size;  i++)` loops. Just put `sum=0;` before the first loop and include `sum+=ara[i];` in that same loop. e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &ara[i]) == 1) { sum += ara[i]; }`. NOTE: Always, *always*, ***check the return*** of any input function used so you validate whether the input succeeded or failed. (**especially** when relying on `scanf()` for numeric conversion) Also be aware that `int ara[size];` creates a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) which is optional for compiler support beginning with C11 (most all will continue to provide support)

Answer (score 1):

The C code for calculating the percentage of element `i` would be:

```
int percentage = 100 * ara[i] / sum;
printf("%d\n", percentage);
```

Note that we do the multiplication first, since the division introduces rounding errors.

I'm just assuming that the elements are small enough so that `100 * ara[i]` doesn't overflow your system's `int` type.  You can cast `100` to a larger type if that's not true.

Here is alternative code if you want a floating point answer:

```
float percentage = 100.0 * ara[i] / sum;
printf("%.2f\n", percentage);
```

Comment: My program is supposed to be like this.

Enter array length:
4

Enter elements
1
2
2
1

Sum
6

1 is 16.67percent of the sum
2 is 33.33 percent of the sum
2 is 33.33 percent of the sum
1 is 16.67percent of the sum

I'm just starting, I've tried searching but I still can't do it.

Comment: I've shown you how to print the part that looks like "33.33".  You see the string that I am passing as the first argument to printf, right?  You can add more text and formatting commands to that.

Comment: I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP, I'VE GOT IT, THANK YOU

Comment: Cool!  Please click the checkmark by my answer to accept the answer.